# QVector vs QList

Tags: c++, qt, list, vector

I have a list of integers that I need to iterate over but an array is inadequate.
What are the differences between `vectors` and `lists` and is there anything I need to know before I pick a type?

Just to be clear, I've read the QT docs but this is the extent of what I know:

> `QList<T>`, `QLinkedList<T>`, and `QVector<T>` provide similar functionality. Here's an overview:
>
> - For most purposes, `QList` is the right class to use. Its index-based API is more convenient than `QLinkedList's` iterator-based API, and it is usually faster than `QVector` because of the way it stores its items in memory. It also expands to less code in your executable.
> - If you need a real linked list, with guarantees of constant time insertions in the middle of the list and iterators to items rather than indexes, use `QLinkedList`.
> - If you want the items to occupy adjacent memory positions, use `QVector`.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

`QVector` is mostly analogous to `std::vector`, as you might guess from the name.  `QList` is closer to `boost::ptr_deque`, despite the apparent association with `std::list`.  It does not store objects directly, but instead stores pointers to them.  You gain all the benefits of quick insertions at both ends, and reallocations involve shuffling pointers instead of copy constructors, but lose the spacial locality of an actual `std::deque` or `std::vector`, and gain a lot of heap allocations.  It does have some decision making to avoid the heap allocations for small objects, regaining the spacial locality, but from what I understand it only applies to things smaller than an `int`.

`QLinkedList` is analogous to `std::list`, and has all the downsides of it.  Generally speaking, this should be your last choice of a container.

The QT library heavily favors the use of `QList` objects, so favoring them in your own code can sometimes avoid some unneccessary tedium.  The extra heap use and the random positioning of the actual data can theoretically hurt in some circumstances, but oftentimes is unnoticable.  So I would suggest using `QList` until profiling suggests changing to a `QVector`.  If you expect contiguous allocation to be important [read: you are interfacing with code that expects a `T[]` instead of a `QList<T>`] that can also be a reason to start off with `QVector` right off the bat.

---

If you are asking about containers in general, and just used the QT documents as a reference, then the above information is less useful.

An `std::vector` is an array that you can resize.  All the elements are stored next to each other, and you can access individual elements quickly.  The downside is that insertions are only efficient at one end.  If you put something in the middle, or at the beginning, you have to copy the other objects to make room.  In big-oh notation, insertion at the end is O(1), insertion anywhere else is O(N), and random access is O(1).

An `std::deque` is similar, but does not guarentee objects are stored next to each other, and allows insertion at both ends to be O(1).  It also requires smaller chunks of memory to be allocated at a time, which can sometimes be important.  Random access is O(1) and insertion in the middle is O(N), same as for a `vector`.  Spacial locality is worse than `std::vector`, but objects tend to be clustered so you gain some benefits.

An `std::list` is a linked list.  It requires the most memory overhead of the three standard sequential containers, but offers fast insertion anywhere... provided you know in advance where you need to insert.  It does not offer random access to individual elements, so you have to iterate in O(N).  But once there, the actual insertion is O(1).  The biggest benefit to `std::list` is that you can splice them together quickly... if you move an entire range of values to a different `std::list`, the entire operation is O(1).  It is also much harder to invalidate references into the list, which can sometimes be important.

As a general rule, I prefer `std::deque` to `std::vector`, unless I need to be able to pass the data to a library that expects a raw array.  `std::vector` is guaranteed contiguous, so `&v[0]` works for this purpose.  I don't remember the last time I used a `std::list`, but it was almost certainly because I needed the stronger guaretee about references remaining valid.

Comment: FWIW, std::deque has pretty good guarantees about references. Iterators are easily invalidated, but pointers to members are pretty robust to operations on the dequeue.

Comment: Great answer. But I have an additional question: Which is faster to iterate? I have a set of objects, they aren't really inserted or removed often, but I need to iterate over the objects as fast as possible. Which is faster?

Comment: Good info.  I found the following statement most useful... "The QT library heavily favors the use of QList objects".  In my use case, I am dealing with a QTableWidget, which likes QList and QListString.  Therefore, let your use case dictate your decision between QVector and QList.

Comment: Have you acually benchmarked `std::deque` against `std::vector`? You will be surprised...

Comment: Please bear in mind that the documentation has been updated following complains from Qt developers that QList is a poor recommendation as a default container. It now states: "**[QVector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html) should be your default first choice. [...] However, [QList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html) is used throughout the Qt APIs for passing parameters and for returning values. Use [QList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html) to interface with those APIs.**" [(QList documentation)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#details)

Comment: Furthermore, in Qt 6, QVector has been removed and replaced with an alias to QList, and QList has been replaced by the QVector's implementation, thus making both classes the same, and equal to the old QVector

Answer (score 91):

**Things have changed**

We are now in Qt 5.8 and things have changed, so the documentation. It gives a clear and different answer to this question :

> `QVector` should be your default first choice. `QVector<T>` will usually
>   give better performance than `QList<T`>, because `QVector<T>` always
>   stores its items sequentially in memory, where `QList<T>` will allocate
>   its items on the heap unless `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*)` and T has been
>   declared to be either a `Q_MOVABLE_TYPE` or a `Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE` using
>   `Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO`.
>
> See the Pros and Cons of Using `QList` for an
>   explanation. However, `QList` is used throughout the Qt APIs for passing
>   parameters and for returning values. Use `QList` to interface with those
>   APIs.

Comment: This should go up, and now be accepted as the answer.

Comment: Same comment as in the other answer: in Qt 6, QVector has been removed and replaced with an alias to QList, and QList has been replaced by the QVector's implementation, thus making both classes the same, and equal to the old QVector

Comment: Besides making things confusing what was the reason for that? Do you have a link?

Comment: @KcFnMi [Qt explained](https://qt.io/blog/qlist-changes-in-qt-6): "Previously, Qt featured very different implementations[...]: QVector being a natural and straightforward array-like container and QList being rather special in its implementation to nicely accommodate types defined and used by Qt itself. With Qt 6 updates to existing types, [...] it seemed that there is little to no benefit to have an implementation difference between the classes. Additionally, QVector proved to be a better choice in many cases.
Thus, in Qt 6, QVector and QList are unified and the model of QVector is used..."

Answer (score 13):

In `QVector` is similar to `std::vector`. `QLinkedList` is similar to `std::list`. `QList` is an index based vector, but the memory position is not guaranteed (like `std::deque`).

Answer (score 3):

From QtList doc:

- QList to be used in most cases. For structures with a thousand of items, enables efficient insertion in the middle, and provides indexed-access. `prepend()` and `append()` very fast since memory is preallocated at both ends of the internal array. `QList<T>` is an array of pointer of type T. If T has a pointer or Qt shared-like pointer type, object is stored directly in array
- `QVector` to be preferred in case of a lot of `append()` or `insert()` of new items with size larger than a pointer since `QVector` allocates memory for its items in a single heap allocation. For `QList`, insert of append of a new item requires memory allocation of the new item on the heap. In short, if you want the items to occupy adjacent memory positions, or if your items are larger than a pointer and you want to avoid the overhead of allocating them on the heap individually at insertion time, then use `QVector`.

Answer (score -3):

`QVector` is like an array that can change size (increase or decrease) but it comes with heavy transactions and computation and time.

For example, if you want to add an item, a new array is created, all the items are copied to new array, the new item is added to the end, and old array is deleted. And vice versa to delete as well.

However, `QLinkedList` works with pointers. So when a new item is created, just a new memory space is allocated and linked to the only chunk of memory. Since it works with pointers it is faster and efficient.

If you have list of items that you do not expect to change size much, `QVector` is probably good, but usually `QLinkedList` is used for most purposes.

Comment: -1: QVector doesn't come with heavy transactions as you claim because it preallocates and has a good grow/shrink strategy for appending and popping. Prepend/insertion indeed requires moving data ranges, but since they're continous in memory this is done very quickly (cache can work well with continous data, unlike with scattered heap chunks as with QList).
Your second statement that QLinkedList is used for most purposes is plain wrong. It is most rarely used. You might be confusing it with QList?