# When can a QList NOT be replaced by a QVector

Tags: qt, crash, qlist, qvector

After [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602036/qvector-vs-qlist) that the `QVector` should be the first choice (over `QList`) for containers in Qt, I merrily changed some of the `QList` in my code to `QVector` and went on with my business, pretty much forgetting about those changes.... until I started getting strange crashes which did not happen before.

The crashes happened in my local copy of the `QQuickTreeModelAdaptor1` class implementation, that I renamed `TreeModelAdaptor`, which is used to display tree-like C++ models in a QML view.

In the header, I replaced:

```
    QList<TreeItem> m_items;
    QList<TreeItem *> m_itemsToExpand;
```

by

```
    QVector<TreeItem> m_items;
    QVector<TreeItem *> m_itemsToExpand;
```

and in the method `TreeModelAdaptor::modelRowsAboutToBeMoved()`

```
const QList<TreeItem> &buffer = m_items.mid(startIndex, totalMovedCount);
```

by:

```
const QVector<TreeItem> &buffer = m_items.mid(startIndex, totalMovedCount);
```

I couldn't figure out why the crashes happened, and then I read the following note on the [QVector doc page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html):

```
Note: Iterators into a QLinkedList and references into heap-allocating QLists 
remain valid as long as the referenced items remain in the container. This is 
not true for iterators and references into a QVector and non-heap-allocating QLists.
```

That's when I remembered the changes I made, and reverted to `QList`. After that, the crashes seemed to be gone.

Can the crashes I experienced be understood in light of the above Note?
The [source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Private/qquicktreemodeladaptor.cpp?h=dev) is a bit too much to post here, but I would appreciate it if someone could point out where and how in the code the above Note would be pertinent?

Also, in light of the above, what about the [unification between `QList` and `QVector`](https://www.qt.io/blog/qlist-changes-in-qt-6) that has been  introduced in Qt6, since it says:

```
QVector is used as the underlying implementation.
```

Does that mean that above code would crash in Qt6 regardless?

EDIT: As @jarman rightfully suggested, the crashes happen at the following `ASSERT`, *almost* randomly. If I expand an item, then do some other expansions on other branches, etc, and toggle expansion on/off a while like that is usually when it happens.

```
void TreeModelAdaptor::expandPendingRows(bool doInsertRows)
{
    while (!m_itemsToExpand.isEmpty()) {
        TreeItem *item = m_itemsToExpand.takeFirst();

        Q_ASSERT(item->expanded);

        const QModelIndex &index = item->index;
        int childrenCount = m_model->rowCount(index);
        if (childrenCount == 0) {
            if (m_model->hasChildren(index) && m_model->canFetchMore(index))
                m_model->fetchMore(index);
            continue;
        }
        // TODO Pre-compute the total number of items made visible
        // so that we only call a single beginInsertRows()/endInsertRows()
        // pair per expansion (same as we do for collapsing).
        showModelChildItems(*item, 0, childrenCount - 1, doInsertRows, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you at least show the code where the crash occurs.

Comment: @JarMan You're absolutely right. I edited my question.

Comment: Here -> `Q_ASSERT(item->expanded);`? Does it crash or asserts after all?

Comment: @vahancho The assert is triggered

Comment: You mentioned you made your own copy of `QQuickTreeModelAdaptor1`. Are the two lines you mentioned the only things that you changed from the original?

Comment: @JarMan Yes, I changed nothing else.